# Data from Sharepoint REST API is returning undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I've this code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Negocio/_api/web/folders('Historico')/folders?$select=ID,Title,Created,Name",
                    type: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    },        

                    success: onQuerySucceeded,
                    error: onQueryFailed
                });


            });

            function onQuerySucceeded(data) 
            {
                console.log(data.d.results);
                var dataresult = data.d.results;
                dataresult = [].slice.call(dataresult);
                dataresult.forEach(function(key, value){

                console.log(value.Name);

                });
            }

            function onQueryFailed() {
                alert('Sorry An Error Has Occurred!');
            }
```

Return this:

[image]

How can I retrieve the *Name*?

Comment: it should be `key.Name` in the foreach loop

Comment: great, have posted that as answer :)  You can accept it which will help us remove it from list of unanswered questions. Thanks & cheers !

Comment: Also, that undefined at the bottom is likely nothing to do with your API call. Chrome just does this in the console. So what you're seeing is the initial console.log of your entire dataset, then Chrome's confusing undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the code as below:

```
dataresult.forEach(function(key, value){    
       console.log(key.Name);    
});
```

Here, `key` represents the element in the array and `value` here represents index.

Reference - [Array forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already loading jQuery, you can shorten your success function to this.

```
function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
        console.log(value.Name);
    });
}
```